# How to insert whitespace between characters of words in a specific field in a file

Tags: bash, awk, processing-efficiency

I have a file containing 100000 lines like this

```
1 0110100010010101
2 1000010010111001
3 1000011001111000
10 1011110000111110
123 0001000000100001
```

I would like to know how can I display efficiently just the second field by adding whitespaces between characters.

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

One solution would be to get the second column with awk and then add the whitespaces using sed. But as the file is too long I would like to avoid using pipes. Then I'm wondering if I can do that by just using awk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this ok?

```
awk '{gsub(/./,"& ",$2);print $2}' yourFile
```

**example**

```
kent$  echo "1 0110100010010101
2 1000010010111001
3 1000011001111000"|awk '{gsub(/./,"& ",$2);print $2}'
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

**update**

more than 2 digits in 1st column won't work? I didn't get it:

```
kent$  echo "133 0110100010010101
233 1000010010111001
333 1000011001111000"|awk '{gsub(/./,"& ",$2);print $2}'
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 


gsub(/./,"& ", $2)

1 /./  match any single character
2 "& " & here means the matched string, in this case, each character
3 $2   column 2

so it means, replace each character in 2nd column into the character itself + " ".
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I forgot to mention  that  the first column contains values with more than two digits. Then I think that it would not work.

Comment: could you please explain the meaning of used regular expressions in gsub(/./,"& ",$2)

Answer (score 2):

One way using only `awk`:

```
awk '{ gsub( /./, "& ", $2 ); print $2; }' infile
```

That yields:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

---

**EDIT**: **Kent** and I gave the same implementation, so, for this answer to be a bit more useful, I will add the `sed` one:

```
sed -e 's/^[^ ]* *//; s/./& /g' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a sed alternative:

```
sed -e 's/^.* *//;s/./& /g;s/ $//' file
```

Three comands:

1. Remove the characters and spaces on the start of the line
2. Replace everycharacter with itself followed by a space
3. (Optional) Remove the trailing space at the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution.

```
sed 's/.* //;s/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

It adds an extra space at the end of each line. Add `;s/ $//` to the expression to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\S*\s*//;s/\B/ /g' /file
```